# how to check if JSON string has extra fields in Spark (not specified in the schema)

Tags: python, json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The `from_json` Spark SQL function omits the fields that are not in schema but are present in the raw JSON string. How do I check if extra fields are present in JSON?

e.g

```
df.select(from_json(col("json_string"), schema)))
```

where `json_string` is `{ "field0" : "go", "field1": "test" }`

and schema is only aware of `field0`. How do I check if any extra fields (`field1`) are present in the `json_string`? Spark just omits the `field1` with no obvious way to retrieve the info about its existence.

Comment: Can you check that extra fields are present in json string not with Spark but with one of json libraries? (Because this doesn't depend on scheme, so this is not Spark but json matter.)